# i want to sum this column

Tags: php, laravel

```
<td class="text-center">
@php
$line_sku2= $sell_lines->variations->sub_sku;
$product_weight2 = DB::select('SELECT weight FROM products WHERE sku like ?', [$line_sku2]);
@endphp
    
@foreach($product_weight2 as $weight2)
@php
$line_weight2 = $sell_lines->quantity * $weight2->weight ;
@endphp
@endforeach 
        
                        {{$line_weight2}} {{ __(' Kg') }}
                        </td>
```

POS system need to modify it with weight value and i',m junior in php

Comment: in SQL, you can use the `SUM` function to sum the values of all the rows in the query result

Comment: you can use array_sum()

Comment: You can initialize a variable to 0 before the loop and add each value to it in each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize a variable and add to it, across your iteration. I have added a snippet below:

```
<td class="text-center">
  @php
    $line_sku2= $sell_lines->variations->sub_sku;
    $product_weight2 = DB::select('SELECT weight FROM products WHERE sku like ?', [$line_sku2]);
  @endphp

  @php
    $total_weight = 0;
  @endphp
    
  @foreach($product_weight2 as $weight2)
    @php
      $line_weight2 = $sell_lines->quantity * $weight2->weight ;
      $total_weight += $line_weight2;
    @endphp
  @endforeach 
        
  {{$total_weight}} {{ __(' Kg') }}
</td>
```

Comment: i need to sum this column

Comment: The sum of the column is seen in `total_weight` variable. However, if you wish to sum a different column, please clarify which column to sum.

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole page i need to sum weight

```js
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close no-print" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"> @lang('lang_v1.stock_transfer_details') (<b>@lang('purchase.ref_no'):</b> #{{ $sell_transfer->ref_no }})
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row invoice-info">
                  <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
                    @lang('lang_v1.location_from'):
                    <address>
                      <strong>{{ $location_details['sell']->name }}</strong>
                      
                      @if(!empty($location_details['sell']->landmark))
                        <br>{{$location_details['sell']->landmark}}
                      @endif

                      @if(!empty($location_details['sell']->city) || !empty($location_details['sell']->state) || !empty($location_details['sell']->country))
                        <br>{{implode(',', array_filter([$location_details['sell']->city, $location_details['sell']->state, $location_details['sell']->country]))}}
                      @endif

                      @if(!empty($sell_transfer->contact->tax_number))
                        <br>@lang('contact.tax_no'): {{$sell_transfer->contact->tax_number}}
                      @endif

                      @if(!empty($location_details['sell']->mobile))
                        <br>@lang('contact.mobile'): {{$location_details['sell']->mobile}}
                      @endif
                      @if(!empty($location_details['sell']->email))
                        <br>Email: {{$location_details['sell']->email}}
                      @endif
                    </address>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-4 invoice-col">
                    @lang('lang_v1.location_to'):
                    <address>
                      <strong>{{ $location_details['purchase']->name }}</strong>
                      
                      @if(!empty($location_details['purchase']->landmark))
                        <br>{{$location_details['purchase']->landmark}}
                      @endif

                      @if(!empty($location_details['purchase']->city) || !empty($location_details['purchase']->state) || !empty($location_details['purchase']->country))
                        <br>{{implode(',', array_filter([$location_details['purchase']->city, $location_details['purchase']->state, $location_details['purchase']->country]))}}
                      @endif

                      @if(!empty($sell_transfer->contact->tax_number))
                        <br>@lang('contact.tax_no'): {{$sell_transfer->contact->tax_number}}
                      @endif

                      @if(!empty($location_details['purchase']->mobile))
                        <br>@lang('contact.mobile'): {{$location_details['purchase']->mobile}}
                      @endif
                      @if(!empty($location_details['purchase']->email))
                        <br>Email: {{$location_details['purchase']->email}}
                      @endif
                    </address>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
                    <b>@lang('purchase.ref_no'):</b> #{{ $sell_transfer->ref_no }}<br/>
                    <b>@lang('messages.date'):</b> {{ @format_date($sell_transfer->transaction_date) }}<br/>
                    <b>@lang('sale.status'):</b> {{$statuses[$sell_transfer->status] ?? ''}}
                  </div>
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table bg-gray">
                        <tr class="bg-green">
                          <th>#</th>
                          <th>@lang('sale.product')</th>
                          <th>@lang('sale.qty')</th>
                          <th>@lang('sale.subtotal')</th>
                          <th>
                        {{ __('Total Weight') }}
                    </th>
                        </tr>
                        @php 
                          $total = 0.00;
                        @endphp
                        @foreach($sell_transfer->sell_lines as $sell_lines)
                          <tr>
                            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                            <td>
                              {{ $sell_lines->product->name }}
                               @if( $sell_lines->product->type == 'variable')
                                - {{ $sell_lines->variations->product_variation->name}}
                                - {{ $sell_lines->variations->name}}
                               @endif
                               - {{ $sell_lines->variations->sub_sku}}
                               @if($lot_n_exp_enabled && !empty($sell_lines->lot_details))
                                <br>
                                <strong>@lang('lang_v1.lot_n_expiry'):</strong> 
                                @if(!empty($sell_lines->lot_details->lot_number))
                                  {{$sell_lines->lot_details->lot_number}}
                                @endif
                                @if(!empty($sell_lines->lot_details->exp_date))
                                  - {{@format_date($sell_lines->lot_details->exp_date)}}
                                @endif
                               @endif
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ @format_quantity($sell_lines->quantity) }} @if(!empty($sell_lines->sub_unit)) {{$sell_lines->sub_unit->short_name}} @else {{$sell_lines->product->unit->short_name}} @endif</td>
                            <td>
                              <span class="display_currency" data-currency_symbol="true">{{ $sell_lines->unit_price_inc_tax * $sell_lines->quantity }}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center">
@php
$line_sku2= $sell_lines->variations->sub_sku;
$product_weight2 = DB::select('SELECT weight FROM products WHERE sku like ?', [$line_sku2]);
@endphp
    
@foreach($product_weight2 as $weight2)
@php
$line_weight2 = $sell_lines->quantity * $weight2->weight ;
@endphp
@endforeach 
        
                        {{$line_weight2}} {{ __(' Kg') }}
                        </td>
                          </tr>
                          @php 
                            $total += ($sell_lines->unit_price_inc_tax * $sell_lines->quantity);
                          @endphp
                        @endforeach
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                  
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                          <th>@lang('purchase.net_total_amount'): </th>
                          <td></td>
                          <td><span class="display_currency pull-right" data-currency_symbol="true">{{ $total }}</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        @if( !empty( $sell_transfer->shipping_charges ) )
                          <tr>
                            <th>@lang('purchase.additional_shipping_charges'):</th>
                            <td><b>(+)</b></td>
                            <td><span class="display_currency pull-right" data-currency_symbol="true">{{ $sell_transfer->shipping_charges }}</span></td>
                          </tr>
                        @endif
                        <tr>
                          <th>@lang('purchase.purchase_total'):</th>
                          <td></td>
                          <td><span class="display_currency pull-right" data-currency_symbol="true" >{{ $sell_transfer->final_total }}</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <th>{{ __('Total Weight') }}: </th>
              <td></td>
              
                @php
$line_sku2= $sell_lines->variations->sub_sku;
$product_weight2 = DB::select('SELECT weight FROM products WHERE sku like ?', [$line_sku2]);
@endphp
    
@foreach($product_weight2 as $weight2)
@php
$line_weight2 = $sell_lines->quantity * $weight2->weight ;
$total_weight5 += $line_weight2 ;
$total_weight += $line_weight ;
@endphp
@endforeach 
    
              <td><span class="pull-right">{{$total_weight }}{{ __(' Kg') }}</span></td>
              
            
              <td class="text-center">
                        </td>
                        
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <strong>@lang('purchase.additional_notes'):</strong><br>
                    <p class="well well-sm no-shadow bg-gray">
                      @if($sell_transfer->additional_notes)
                        {{ $sell_transfer->additional_notes }}
                      @else
                        --
                      @endif
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                        <strong>{{ __('lang_v1.activities') }}:</strong><br>
                        @includeIf('activity_log.activities', ['activity_type' => 'sell'])
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row print_section">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <img class="center-block" src="data:image/png;base64,{{DNS1D::getBarcodePNG($sell_transfer->ref_no, 'C128', 2,30,array(39, 48, 54), true)}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary no-print" aria-label="Print" 
            onclick="$(this).closest('div.modal-content').printThis();"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> @lang( 'messages.print' )
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default no-print" data-dismiss="modal">@lang( 'messages.close' )</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This 'answer' appears to be simply adding more details to the original post. Instead of posting this as an answer, you need to edit your post with this additional information. It would also help if you provide more details as to the context of the issue.